# How to construct a rolling annual returns from a time series using R?

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation

I have the daily closed values of the initial index  for DJUSER, MSCI, SP500, SPGSCI from 1 January 1999 to 31 December 2011.  I want to transform them in to data of rolling annual returns.

How to do it using R? which package do I need to use?

The density of the rolling annual returns associate to each data should be similar to the graph in the picture :

[image]

I can send to you the initial data if you want to try.

Comment: This question is probably offtopic. Note that R is a programming language and you can code any algorithm you want. It would help a lot if you define a formula of what is a rolling annual return and be more precise of what kind of data you have (daily, hourly, equally spaced, etc.)

Comment: I have daily closed values.

Comment: Please define exactly (with mathematic formula preferably) what do you mean by rolling annual return. Judging by quick google search on term rolling annual return, I can think a number of ways these returns can be calculated. From implementation point of view they are all similar, but for you naturally only one precise definition matters.

Comment: The graphs do not help, since it is not clear what are the blue and red lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `TTR` package's `ROC()` function makes this incredibly easy:

```
ROC(prices, n = 252, type = "discrete")
```

Comment: @Downvoter: It is good practice to give a reason for the downvote and, even better, give an idea how to improve the answer - Thank you.

Comment: I used this package's TTR and Roc(), but I did get the right answer and even I can not plot the density of the transformed data.

Comment: @timelyportfolio: Good to see you here :-)

Comment: This answer assumes that the data has a very nice structure. Wouldn't leap years cause a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the zoo package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html

You are very, very flexible to do all kinds of things, including aggregation and rolling functions:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf

See e.g. p. 6ff. there

Comment: I used the  package Performance analytics but it does not solve my problem

Comment: library(zoo)

SP500 = read.table("SP500.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")

SP500 = as.numeric(SP500[,2])

ret_SP500 = diff(log(SP500))
ret_SP500 <- rollapply(ret_SP500,12,mean)